# Are there any dedicated SMTP/POP providers for a top level domain, SaaS web application

Tags: email, smtp, multi-tenant, pop3, saas

We are in the process of building a Multi-Tenant, SaaS type web app. Everything is set to go on the application part but when it comes to email there is a problem.

Each tenant/user of the application has a subdomain based account. However, there will be the option for that tenant to associate a top level domain to their account. Here is where the problem comes for us.

Basically, if the user sets up their DNS to point to our SaaS web app everything works good on the app front except that it now makes us responsible for handling their Email as well. Incoming and Outgoing.

What is the best way to handle this? I really was hoping their is a 3rd party site that handles outgoing and incoming email for multiple top level domains under one company name but am unsure.

There is always the option of doing our own SMTP/POP service, but we would really like to steer away from the responsibilities of email.

Thanks everyone,

~kvq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't they just setup an A record or a CNAME to point to your servers?

If they did an A record it would allow just webapp.theirdomain.com to go to your severs and everything else can just stay on their DNS.

The other option and maybe a better option is for them to setup a CNAME. Then you can just setup companyA.yourdomain.com and then they can just setup a CNAME that points webapp.theirdomain.com to companyA.yourdomain.com

You really do not want to be responsible for all of their DNS. They can keep their DNS where ever they want and keep their MX records the way they are.

I hope this helps

Comment: Hmm thanks for your input. I was definatly thinking about A records and that may be a possible solution. I like your suggestion for it's simplicity. There are two problems that I can see in the context of my business:

- Sometimes users are coming from no existing solution, and they will look to us for "the solution".

- Most tenants are probably not going to want to pay for 2 services (mine, and the existing webhost that hosts their email)

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: The perfect solution I think would be to use your first suggestion and point their mail mx record to a 3rd party that just handles that stuff for them. I would like it to all be included in the monthly fee that each tenant pays... hmm

Comment: Most domain name authorities offer really good DNS management. Go Daddy or Network Solutions can do everything I said and there is really no additional cost because they have to pay annually for the domain record. Go Daddy is like 7 bucks a year. They do not need other web hosing just a domain name with DNS management which all do.

Comment: Unless it's part of your core business you don't want to get into managing their entire DNS when they can just point to you. That's my opinion. If you manage their entire DNS you will need to build a lot of toots and infrastructure that probably is not going to add a lot to your bottom line.

Comment: I found a great app that will take care of this for you.. it's called Mailgun